# python Script to download data from NOAA

Tags: python-3.x

Following is the script to download the data from NOAA in .sh file formate. How can I download the same data using python for windows operating system?

```
mkdir -p observations
cd observations

for year in `seq 2007 2016`; do
    wget https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/$year/081810-99999-$year.gz
done
```

Comment: Try not to delete posts that people have taken the time to answer. Is there any reason you want to delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

## Untested Installation

```
pip3 install wget
```

## Untested Code

```
import errno
import os
import wget

# Take an absolute path; I've already seen horses puke! ;)
path_ = r'c:\Users\YOUR WINDOWS USERNAME\Desktop\obervations'  


def mkdir_p(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
        return 'Path created.'
    except OSError as exc:  # Python > 2.5
        if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
            return 'Path already exists!'
        else:
            # Otherwise, throw error:
            raise

mkdir_p(path_)

for year in range(2006, 2017):
    url = f'https://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/year/081810-99999-{year}.gz'  # Python > 3.6, otherwise use '…{}…'.format(year)
    filename = wget.download(url, out=path_)
```