# Python 2.7 requests not reading complete body

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to read the body of a web service call with the requests module in Python 2.7.  The body of the result is CSV data.

The request is just a GET.  I can run the url in Chrome and it returns a complete response of 200 rows.  The url looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/summary-report?endTime=9999999&startTime=0
```

When I try to get the data from Python, it retrieves only the first row of data.  I look at the response header and see the length of the response is only 122 bytes, about the length of the first row.  I have run it a number of times from Python and it is consistent in returning only the first row.

The code is only:

```
        r = requests.get(url)
        ans = r.content
```

Could it be some with with the new line characters on each line of the CSV file?
Or because I am using localhost in the url?
I also tried it with 127.0.0.1 but see a similar behavior.
Possibly the ampersand is an issue in the URL?

Comment: Does the page have dynamically generated content?

Comment: Yes.  The page is dynamically generated.

Comment: So that's why. `request.get (url)` gets only the main page of a URL. You can not get dynamically generated content using this.

Comment: I also had tried urllib2 with similar results.  What to use instead?

Comment: You need a JS engine to parse and run javascript, so you will be able to get dynamically generated content.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic' -- I was referring to the server.  The content is just CSV.  There is no JS in the content.

Comment: Maybe my answer to a similar question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455920/1707015

Comment: @qräbnö   I also tried using wget as you suggested, but it has the same behavior

Comment: Maybe it is working, but your output is shown in one line? How do you check that it is only one line?

Comment: If you are unsure what your browser is doing when downloading, you can use Wireshark to read network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can get dinamically generated content with `request.get()`

You need JavaScript Engine to parse and run JavaScript code inside the page. Some of those can be found below:

http://code.google.com/p/spynner/

http://phantomjs.org/

http://zombie.labnotes.org/